# JavaScript Making value to change

Tags: javascript

Hey i want that on button click `html5colorpicker` value would change to `entercolor` value. Im aint't so good at `JavaScripting`, so i scripted only this.... Help pls `javascript:document.getElementById('html5colorpicker').value=''`

And here is all code:

```
<div id="html5DIV">
    <input id="html5colorpicker" name="user_color" class="form-control" onchange="clickColor(0, -1, -1, 5)" value="<?php echo @$user['user_color'];?>" type="color">
</div>
<div id="entercolorDIV" class="input-group">
    <input id="entercolor" name="user_color" class="form-control" placeholder="Spalvos kodas" value="<?php echo @$user['user_color'];?>" onfocus="clearWrongInput();" type="text">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('html5colorpicker').value=''">OK</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
document.getElementById('html5colorpicker').value = document.getElementById('entercolor').value;
```

Comment: Which part fails? Getting the value from the 'entercolor' or setting the value of the 'html5colorpicker'?

Comment: Check if you correctly select the input node. Check in the object inspector if the php gave the input a value. Check if your clearWrongInput function doesn't remove the value again. etc

Answer (score 0):

Solved! :)

```
<script>
    function changeValue(){
        var x = document.getElementById("entercolor").value;
        document.getElementById("html5colorpicker").value = x;
    }
    function changeValue2(){
        document.getElementById("entercolor").value = '';
    }
</script>

<div id="html5DIV">
    <input id="html5colorpicker" name="user_color" class="form-control" onchange="clickColor(0, -1, -1, 5)" onclick="changeValue2()" value="<?php echo @$user['user_color'];?>" type="color"/>
</div>
<div id="entercolorDIV" class="input-group">
    <input id="entercolor" style="width:50px" name="user_color2" class="text" placeholder="Spalvos kodas" value="<?php echo @$user['user_color'];?>" onfocus="clearWrongInput();" type="text"/>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="changeValue()">OK</button>
    </span>
</div>
```